# Method Local Inner Class

Tags: java, inner-classes, method-invocation

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}

class Outer {
    void aMethod() {
        class MethodLocalInner {
            void bMethod() {
                System.out.println("Inside method-local bMethod");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how to print the message from `bMethod`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only instantiate `MethodLocalInner` within `aMethod`. So do

```
void aMethod() {

    class MethodLocalInner {

            void bMethod() {

                    System.out.println("Inside method-local bMethod");
            }
    }

    MethodLocalInner foo = new MethodLocalInner(); // Default Constructor
    foo.bMethod();

}
```

Comment: Thanks..realised where I went wrong..I put the new instance line before the localinner class creation.

Answer (score 1):

Within the method *aMethod* after the declaration of the class *MethodLocalInner* you could for instance do the following call:

```
new MethodLocalInner().bMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create an instance of `MethodLocalInner`, in `aMethod`, and call `bMethod` on the new instance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call new Outer().aMethod() inside your main method. You also need to add a reference to MethodLocalInner().bMethod() inside your aMethod(), like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Outer().aMethod();
    }
}


void aMethod() {
    class MethodLocalInner {
        void bMethod() {
            System.out.println("Inside method-local bMethod");
        }
    }
    new MethodLocalInner().bMethod();
}
```